# Two double quotes around preprocessor token in macro definition

Tags: c++, c++11, string-literals, user-defined-literals

I don't understand the significance of using two double quotes with strings in C++. I saw the following code somewhere:

```
class str_literal;
static str_literal operator"" _s(const char *s, size_t len);

class str_literal {
private:
  explicit str_literal(const char *s)
      : m_str(s) //&(STRING_LITERAL(s)))
  {}
  const char *m_str;

public:
  friend str_literal operator"" _s(const char *s, size_t len);
};
static str_literal operator"" _s(const char *s, size_t len) {
  return str_literal(s);
}
#define S(str) "" str "" _s
```

Why not make the constructor public and just do this?

```
#define S(str) str_literal(str)
```

Comment: The preprocessor would no be able to distinguish `str` inside `str_s`, in order to replace it with the input argument. There is a specific set of proper delimiters which allow the preprocessor to determine the tokens in every given expression (white spaces, round brackets, and that's pretty much it I believe).

Comment: Got it. Removed the last part of question. Still is that the only purpose of using two double quotes ? I am seeing this syntax for the first time.

Comment: I think this should help answer your question https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal if you're not just referring to the preprocessor stringify

Comment: The constructor isn't public in order to disable the creation of "non-literal literals" ; you're not supposed to be able to write `str_literal(some_function())`.

Comment: [how-to-compose-stringification-with-user-defined-literal-udl-in-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58868807/2684539) shows alternative to string concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They’re unnecessary. Whoever wrote the code probably intended to use the fact that you the preprocessor concatenates successive C string literals into one literal so that e.g. `S("hi")` results in `"" "hi" ""_s`, which, in turn, results in `"hi"_s`.

However, there is no need to have the first `""` in the macro definition. And there’s no need for the second `""` either, since we can use the [token pasting operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators) `##` instead:

```
#define S(str) str ## _s
```

This has the exact same effect, and is idiomatic.

Comment: Why not do `#define S(str) ""str""_s` ? What's the importance of spaces?

Comment: (Most of) the spaces are also unnecessary but many people would find this confusing, because `""`, `str` and `""` are actually distinct tokens, yet putting them directly adjacent without spaces suggests that they form a single preprocessor token. Similarly in my code, `##` is an operator, so I always surround it with spaces. What’s more, there *needs* to be a space between the initial `""` and `str`, because `""str` *does* form a token for the preprocessor, so it won’t try replacing `str`.